# Is ColorStateList Serialization/De-serialization Possible

Tags: android

Is there a way to serialize and deserialize a [ColorStateList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList)? If it can be represented by an XML it would seem that it should be possible.

Comment: It does not appear that you will be able to do that directly, insofar as the available getter methods do not seem to line up with the available constructor.